# REACT connect 4 game - attempt to reset grid over setState but results in "undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a Connect of 4 game in React as an exercise.
If i want to reset the grid or for displaying player points, a reset of my grid is required rather than simply reloading the entire page.
In this case, dealing with my grid via state is a logical step, but after several attempts and variations, I'm unfortunately lost at the moment

In this variation below, this.state.grid always returns undefined on reset (console.log right after render method begins).
I see that the problem is most likely because in the gridHtml function I am already passing the grid to the state via setState.
If I call this.gridHTML() directly on the reset button, my grid completely disappears.

I am very grateful for any help at this point

```
    import React from 'react';



class Grid extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            player: "red",
            isGameOver: false,
            gamestarts: false
        };
        this.findLastEmptyColl = this.findLastEmptyColl.bind(this);
        this.onMouseEnter = this.onMouseEnter.bind(this);
        this.onMouseLeave = this.onMouseLeave.bind(this);
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
        this.checkForWinner = this.checkForWinner.bind(this);
        this.gridHtml = this.gridHtml.bind(this);
        this.reset = this.reset.bind(this);
    };

/*left out MouseEnter, leave, click and win logic , those work fine and to keep it short */

    gridHtml() {
        let rows = Array(6).fill(0), cols = Array(7).fill(0);
        let grid = rows.map((el, i) => {
            return (
                <div key={i} className="row">
                    {cols.map((value, index) => {
                        return (
                                <div key={index} 
                                    onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnter}
                                    onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave}
                                    onClick={this.onClick}
                                    className="col empty" 
                                    data-col={index}
                                    data-row={i}>
                                </div>
                            );
                    })}
                </div>
            );
        });
        
        this.setState({
            grid: grid
        });

    }

    

    componentDidMount() {
        this.gridHtml();
    }
    
    componentWillMount() {
        this.gridHtml();
    }    
    
    reset() {
        
        this.setState({
            grid: this.gridHtml(),
            isGameOver: false,
            gamestarts: false
        })
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.grid);
        return (
            <>
                {!this.state.gamestarts && <h4>Connect 4 - Player {this.state.player} begins!</h4>}
                {this.state.gamestarts && <h4>Player {this.state.player} </h4>}
                {(this.state.isGameOver && !this.state.gamestarts) && <h4>Player {this.state.player} has won</h4>}
                <div id="board">
                    {this.state.grid}
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button style={{margin: "30px"}} onClick={() => {this.reset()}}>Reset</button>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default Grid;
```

### Update:

I see that my understanding of React doesn't seem to be properly adjusted yet; in my reset() function, due to the asynchronicity of react, I assume that the dynamic assignment via setState of my grid should actually render automatically?
Again, the problem: when I currently press my reset button, the grid is re-created but the moves, red and yellow, are still on the grid as they were; last I thought of writing a function that instead of creating a new grid removes all CSS classes and data properties related to it - but that would make the whole point of doing something like this with React absurd.

To make it even clearer:
if I extend my reset() function with a setTimeout around setState, right after overwriting my grid, it works?! I can understand why but this right now feels like a hack and I don't want to leave it like this, because this is supposed to be the core competence of React? Hope it helps to understand better

```
reset () {
    this.setState({grid: 'some text ... loading '});
    setTimeout(() =>{
        this.setState({
            grid: this.gridHtml(),
            isGameOver: false,
            gamestarts: true,
            player: "red"
        });
    }, 1000);
}
```

Hope somebody can explain?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your gridHtml() function doesn't return anything so grid is being set to undefined. Try adding a return grid; statement to the end.

Comment: Hi Hayden, thanks for your comment! 
I assumed that if gridHtml builds my HTML and puts it into the grid property via setState, that it doesn't need a return?
It hasn't come to my mind to try setState plus return, tried it, but unfortunately that doesn't work either; 
So to avoid misunderstandings: I put "return grid" inside gridHTml() at the very end - after this.setState ... 
Or you meant it differently?
Thanks again!

Comment: to be more specific: what it no longer does with your suggestion is that the grid no longer disappears. But it doesn't reset in the sense and still has the game moves in the same place ; Thx!

Comment: @StJungDev is gridHtml called outside of just resetting the grid and initializing it? If not you could try making it do a full state reset when called. Just remove the reset function and instead have gridHtml set both isGameOver and gamestarts to false. If that still doesn't work try putting a console.log statement inside the gridHtml function so you can compare the grid before the setState to the one in the render function.

Comment: gridHtml is not called outside so far. I updated my post just before your new answer. 
Already before, when I called grid via console, it was created, but the moves were not reset; see my update: it works when I overwrite it and give grid a setTimeout via setState. I think I understand that with this solution it is bypassing core principles of React - I think I'm still miss or don't fully understand something; what you think? Thank you!

Comment: @StJungDev if using a setTimeout is making the state call go through then that means you probably have another state call after your one in the reset function that is overriding the grid. When you call setState it doesn't immediately update the state, rather it queues the updates which it will then execute before rerendering. You can read about setState [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thx man, really appreciate it, unfortunately I don't discover anything new or helpful - forceUpdate might be something but is not recommended;